# Excel Pivot Table Field headers are too large

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm working in excel doing pivot tables and the field list is too large. It is hard to see what headings are in 'rows' here for example. I've tried zooming out and in to no avail and connecting it to a larger monitor but it doesn't help.

I have also tried changing to display settings from 'optimize for best appearance' to 'optimize for compatibility' but nothing changes.

Any help would be great,
Thanks

[This is the image of the excel field list I am having trouble with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnI9A.png)

Answer (score 0):

I end up with the same sort of issue if my Excel window is only using a portion of the vertical space on the monitor.  If this is the case, maximizing the window should solve the issue.

If you are already maximized, try hitting the gear icon and changing the layout to Area Section Only (2 by 2).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had this problem too.  It's very annoying, and took me a long time to find a solution.  It's an easy fix!  Near the bottom, right-hand corner of your MS Excel window, select "Display Settings."  Then Select the radio-button "Optimize for compatibility."  You will then be asked to close MS Office applications and re-start the application.  It worked for me!  Good luck.